# LocalStorage values are one login behind

Tags: reactjs

I'm having this problem with my AuthContext from a React app. I check the localStorage and the values stored are from the last user logged, so I have to login twice to get the corrent info.
This is the Context code. And the 'useLocalStorage' function. I guess in the useMemo is the problem but I haven't been able to solve it. Is this a bad approach?

```
import { createContext, useContext, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocalStorage } from "./useLocalStorage";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useLocalStorage("accessToken", null);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useLocalStorage("currentUserId", null);
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useLocalStorage("currentUserEmail", null);
  const [userRole, setUserRole] = useLocalStorage("currentUserRole", null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const login = async (credentials) => {
    return fetch("https://localhost:7264/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        setToken(res);
        console.log(res);
        const tokenToDecode = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
        setUser(jwtDecode(tokenToDecode));
        setUserId(user.sub);
        setUserEmail(
          user[
            "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"
          ]
        );
        setUserRole(
          user["http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"]
        );
      });
  };


  const logout = () => {
    setToken(null);
    setUserId(null);
    setUserEmail(null);
    setUserRole(null);
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  };

  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
      token,
      login,
      logout,
      userId,
      userEmail,
      userRole,
    }),
    [token]
  );
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

---

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const useLocalStorage = (keyName, defaultValue) => {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
    try {
      const value = localStorage.getItem(keyName);
      if (value) {
        return JSON.parse(value);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem(keyName, JSON.stringify(defaultValue));
        return defaultValue;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return defaultValue;
    }
  });
  const setValue = (newValue) => {
    try {
      localStorage.setItem(keyName, JSON.stringify(newValue));
    } catch (err) {}
    setStoredValue(newValue);
  };
  return [storedValue, setValue];
};
```

Comment: useMemo will memorize the values until dependencies changes. Try to avoid using useMemo from https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar Ok, I'll try to find a solution outside of that hook. But I don't get why, since when I logout I'm setting everything to null, this is not acquainted by the dependency, in this case, 'token'.

Comment: Try out without useMemo like const value = {token, login, logout, userId, userEmail, userRole}; Can you provide a sandbox demo to check?

Comment: @DhavalGajjar thanks, sorry about the delay. I got it to work as you said and making everything a state but the token.

Comment: Please add code changes you have done as answer for other's reference if they come to this question.